# "%%d was unexpected at this time" in nested FOR loop

Tags: variables, for-loop, cmd

I need to create a set of dummy files for tests. The set consists of seven files for every day in the month. I have created the files for one day manually:

```
2014-10-30  15:58                25 kl141001.001
2014-10-30  15:58                25 ok141001.001
2014-10-30  15:57                25 po141001.001
2014-10-30  15:57                25 um141001.001
2014-10-30  15:57                25 wn141001.001
2014-10-23  12:29                25 FIRMAOVERDUE_141001.001
2014-10-23  12:29                25 CONTRACTOVERDUE_141001.001
```

And now I'm trying to create the rest in a nested FOR loop, but get an error:

```
i:\expleo1410>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

i:\expleo1410>for %%d in  ( 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ) do ( for %%f in ( kl ok po um wn FIRMAOVERDUE_ CONTRACTOVERDUE_ ) do ( copy %%f141001.001 %%f1410"%%d".001 ) )
%%d was unexpected at this time.
```

I tried: 
"%%d" 
%%d 
%%~d 
and get the same error every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From the command-line, as you appear to be doing, you only want one percent: e.g. `%d`